# I need to send and listen to events from a 3rd party JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

We are a social start-up and are given a great opportunity by one of the biggest banks in our country. Basically they will feature our website in their Mobile App, and users can access our website via their app in an iFrame. We are currently working on integrating a SSO log in flow between their app and our website, so users are logged in immediately when they open our website in their app.

For this, they have created an API that we're able to use. The API requires 2 main things to get the flow working:

1. send a pageLoaded() event when the DOM is ready, when this event is sent, we get returned a token to fetch the user's personal information with a public event.
2. send a pageReady() event when the backend logic processing is done (eg account created and user logged in).

They will show a spinner in their app, until the pageReady event is being sent to them.

My website uses PHP and JS (jQuery) as the main technologies. I am having a number of issues on how to implement this correctly.

This is the code I am using as of now, it works in a certain way, but it's very troublesome for the reasons mentioned below the code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var getUrl = window.location;
    var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host;

    /*** Mobile App JS Code ***/
    var receiver = new PostmessageExternalReceiver();
    var sender = new PostmessageExternalSender();

    receiver.addTokenEventListener(function (api, token, version){
        if (api == 'init') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                url: baseUrl + '/login/abc/abcLogin',
                data: {
                    'token': token
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    sender.pageReady();
                    window.location.replace(response.redirect_url);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    sender.pageLoaded();
});
```

These are the problems that i'm not sure how to get around:

1. Since the sender.pageLoaded(); is in the jQuery document ready, and after performing the AJAX request, we are redirecting again to the same page (the homepage), because after the redirect, the user will be logged in and some extra blocks will show on the homepage. So if we are on the homepage again, the document ready will fire yet another sender.pageLoaded() event, and we are stuck in an infinite redirecting loop.
2. Right now I am including all 4 API javascript libraries provided by our third party, and my own javascript file including the AJAX request and the pageLoaded() and pageReady(). This is only applicable for users that come to our website via the 3rd party mobile app. For all other visitors in our website this is not applicable and requires extra resources to be loaded in when they're not used. (the ajax request will never be executed for them because a token will not be sent via the mobile app, but still we do not want to send a pageLoaded() for every visitor on our website, even if he is not from the mobile app.
3. This is a nice-to-have question: since we need to send the pageReady() after our PHP logic (via AJAX request) is done, we cannot do the redirect in PHP, so I return the redirect_url in my AJAX and then do the window.location.replace() method with the redirect URL. In the 3rd party app, this will cause the app to remove the spinner (on the pageReady() event) and show our website, but immediately afterwards we will redirect the user using the window.location.replace() , this causes a refresh of the page, and thus a small annoyance and not so smooth experience for the user. They expect after the spinner is gone that the website is immediately accessible. How would I go around this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: 1. If you're redirecting to the same page, why do you need to redirect? It's unclear.

Comment: 2. Maybe have a different landing page for app-based visitors then? This could also help with 1. potentially, if you redirect from the landing page to the main home page. Alternatively, maybe pass some querystring parameters from the app, which PHP uses to decide what JavaScript resources to add to the HTML. Or perhaps you could do some user-agent matching, or something.

Comment: 3. See point 1 - consider if a redirect is really necessary here.

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot for your answers. To give more context for number 1, in my AJAX request I set the cookies and do everything necessary to log the user in using PHP, but without a page refresh, the user will not notice that he is logged in (until he clicks on a link). So we redirect him to the homepage again, so the page refreshes, and it will become clear that he or she is logged in automatically. The content on the homepage will be specific for that user's settings as well.

Comment: "the user will not notice that he is logged in"...you could always just use JavaScript to add/remove anything on the page which needs to change after a successful login. If necessary you could do another AJAX request to pull down new HTML and replace what's already there. That's usually how AJAX-based login systems would do it.

Comment: @ADyson that's also an option I thought of indeed. However, since we have a VERY strict deadline (it's a 2 week deadline, due to some specific methodology the company is testing out), i'm not confident in myself to be able to transform our website to work with everything using AJAX (it's quite a lot that changes), since I only have 3 days left

Comment: surely only the home page would need to be altered, for this purpose initially? You could always propose to change the rest later, if it works. And you could add it on as new functionality rather than modifying anything existing. That should reduce effort, cost and risk.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your replies, you've given me new insights to continue working on this problem! Thanks a lot!